# Is there a way in ruby to untoggle escape characters completely from strings?

Tags: ruby

I am building a ruby gem that displays ASCII art to the command line. Because ASCII art includes so many different types of characters, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to deal with escape characters (backslashes).

It would be wonderful if I could change the backslash character to something less common for this particular gem, although I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. Also, I suspect that this may cause more problems with special characters that are expressed with backslashes (such as tabs and new line returns).

One of the things I have tried is to use single quotes, which is fine for a single backslash situations, but often times there will be many backslashes in a row and this will not work.

Here is a simplified example of what I am talking about. I have a string:

```
"How \ are \\ you \\\ doing \\\\ this \\\\\ afternoon"
```

I would like to take the above string input, and puts it exactly the way it is shown. But when I puts it, it shows:

```
 => "How  are \\ you \\ doing \\\\ this \\\\ afternoon"
```

If I use single quotes I get this:

```
 => How  are \ you \ doing \\ this \\ afternoon
```

This application I am building is really just a fun project for myself, but I am curious how one should approach such a situation in ruby.

Thank you in advance for your time and ideas!

Edit:

The example is simplified. I will ultimately be using ASCII art (See Here: https://www.asciiart.eu/mythology/skeletons ). I am looking for an abstracted way of modifying the ASCII art pieces to display correctly in the terminal window using puts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslash to [escape backslash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) in double quotes.

```
puts "How \\ are \\\\ you \\\\\\ doing \\\\\\\\ this \\\\\\\\\\ afternoon"

# will print
# How \ are \\ you \\\ doing \\\\ this \\\\\ afternoon
```

Another way to use [heredoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) with single quotes

```
puts <<~'TEXT'
How \ are \\ you \\\ doing \\\\ this \\\\\ afternoon
TEXT

# will print
# How \ are \\ you \\\ doing \\\\ this \\\\\ afternoon
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I will be using strings of ASCII art (see this example if you dont know what that is: https://www.asciiart.eu/mythology/skeletons ). I cannot manually manipulate the hundreds of different art pieces. I am seeking an abstracted way of doing this. One thing that came to mind was .gsub(/\\/,"\\\\"), but alas this does not work either.

Comment: I had never heard of heredocs prior to your comment. This looks interesting as well. Thank you!

Comment: Nice. You probably should use something longer than just `_` because it will probably appear somewhere in the ASCII art.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Maybe you're right. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping of the backslashes in string literals is a part of the Ruby parser - you cannot simply turn this off. And being part of the parser it works *only* for literals that are part of the program code itself. But if you read the string from a file, STDIN or whatever else it is being read as is.

Just try to put this string into a file and then

```rb
puts File.readlines(<filename>) # => How \ are \\ you \\\ doing \\\\ this \\\\\ afternoon
```

So if you need these crazy backslashes sequences in the ruby code itself - escape backslashes manually. But if you are reading them as an input to your program it should work out of the box...

Comment: @AllenP., I recommend to use `File.read` instead of `File.readlines` in this case. It will save RAM and it will faster because it returns `String`, not `Array`.